# Nonlinear second order partial differential equation Integration

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, soliton-theory

I have the following nonlinear second order partial differential equation:

$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \log(1 + u) = \nabla^2 u.$

My question is how can i use a finite differences scheme to integrate this?. I tried using finite differences directly in the logarithm
but apparently it is not the best way.

I will be grateful if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Define $v = \log (1+u)$, then $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}v = \nabla^2e^v$. This should be much more tractable. Literature on the Bratu problem may be helpful here. Additionally, no boundary conditions are provided so the problem is ill-posed.